# google fit request for per minute steps

Tags: android, google-fit

I am trying to read the steps per minute data for the last 5 days, but it returns only 1 day's steps per minute. Below is the code I am using to get the last 5 days' steps per minute.

1. Last 5 days' steps
2. Steps per minute

   ```
   private void displayMinData() {
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       Date now = new Date();
       cal.setTime(now);
       long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

       int lastSyncDays=5;
       cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, lastSyncDays);
       long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
       try {
           String strEndTime = millisToHMS(endTime);
           String strStartTime= millisToHMS(startTime);
       }
       catch(ParseException pe)
       {
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
       }

       java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
       Log.e("History", "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
       Log.e("History", "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

       //Check how many steps were walked and recorded in the last 7 days
       DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
               .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
               .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
               .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
               .build();

       DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

       //Used for aggregated data
       if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
           Log.e("History", "Number of buckets: " + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
           for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
               List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
               for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                   showDataSet(dataSet);
               }
           }
       }
       //Used for non-aggregated data
       else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
           Log.e("History", "Number of returned DataSets: " + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
           for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
               showDataSet(dataSet);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

So I did a *little* testing with the same query and found some things that would probably good to explore more in depth.

First, one problem I see in your code is that you are not asking for the step count for the *past* 5 days, but rather the *next* 5 days. You add 5 days to the current time, not subtract it.

```
int lastSyncDays=5;
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, lastSyncDays);
```

It should instead be

```
int lastSyncDays=5;
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -lastSyncDays);
```

In my testing it seems that the amount of data you can query is limited. When asking for the cumulative step count per minute in the past day the results came back quickly, much earlier than the 1 minute wait time. I tried 2 days and I got a request timeout. I tried 2 days with a 5 minute wait time and the request still timed out, so I don't think that's the issue.

The other thing I tried was 2 days worth of cumulative step counts, but with 2 minute buckets instead of 1 minute. The results came back just as quickly as the original 1 day request. I tried again with a request for 4 days, using 4 minute buckets and the result was the same.

I don't know the exact limits of what we can query and Google's documentation doesn't seem to give much help in that regard. But perhaps you can create 5 separate requests for 1 day each and combine the data for your uses. One request seems quick enough, but I'm not sure if there's any consequences to using multiple requests vs. one (if one request would work).